# JSON Template Failing with Active deployment in loop

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create a template which does multiple vm's in Azure and then encrypts the disks, I've managed to get it working with 2 vm's about 3 hours ago, however when I do three of more vm's in the loop I get the following error:

```
            "code": "DeploymentFailed",
        "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
        "details": [
          {
            "code": "Conflict",
            "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"DeploymentActive\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Unable to edit or replace deployment 'updatevm': previous deployment 
from '12/29/2018 1:11:34 AM' is still active (expiration time is '1/5/2019 1:11:34 AM'). Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Is there a way of putting a pause so it waits for the `updatevm` extension to complete?

The section of code I have for the encryption is:

```
{
      "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'),copyIndex(),'UpdateEncryptionSettings')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('VMNames'),copyIndex(1))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'),'/nestedtemplates/encryptVm.json',parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "vmName": {
            "value": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'), copyIndex(1))]"
          },
          "aadClientID": {
            "value": "[parameters('aadClientID')]"
          },
          "aadClientSecret": {
            "value": "[parameters('aadClientSecret')]"
          },
          "keyVaultName": {
            "value": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]"
          },
          "keyVaultResourceGroup": {
            "value": "[parameters('keyVaultResourceGroup')]"
          },
          "useExistingKek": {
            "value": "[parameters('useExistingKek')]"
          },
          "keyEncryptionKeyURL": {
            "value": "[parameters('keyEncryptionKeyURL')]"
          },
          "_artifactsLocation": {
            "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocation')]"
          },
          "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
            "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it depend on the previous extension, since you do not provide the exact code, its something like:

```
"dependsOn": [
    "updatevm"
}
```

this didnt exactly work due to how the templates were structured, the answer was to use serial copy mode to only create one copy at a timeю

```
"copy": {
    "name": "storagecopy",
    "count": 4,
    "mode": "serial",
    "batchSize": 1
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#resource-iteration

Comment: lin 453 has dependson the vmname, should that also have the updatevm extension on it or would it be line 434 where it has the monitoring extension. I use powershell to call the template and parameter JSON files, the copyIndex has been added to this template (as you mentioned on a previous question)

Comment: I've got to pop out for 2 hours ..shoppng.. be back in a bit

Comment: Hi Any joy with this code? Which line should I be putting the "dependsOn"

Comment: Hi, the powershell code and the updateVM json is all in the link below, the first 6 lines are the powershell and the rest is the nested json template, link = https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/Bdk0Kv8J

Comment: please, add `"mode": "serial",` to the place where you iterate over something (VM?) that creates these deployments, i cant figure out where exactly do you invoke [this](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/Bdk0Kv8J) updatevm, i suppose its one of the vm "extensions"\sub resources. so you need mode serial on the vm resource

Comment: Hi when i put "mode":"Serial" on line 353 I get this error `"message": "Could not find member 'mode' on object of type 'Properties'. Path 'properties.mode', line 1, position 241.",` and when I change the change the mode from incremental to serial on line 458 I get this error  `Message=The nested deployment 'vmr1-ssr1UpdateEncryptionSettings' failed validation: 'Error converting value "serial" to type 
'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Entities.Deployments.DeploymentMode'. Path 'properties.mode'.'.` I thought the nested template called the updatevm deployment.

Comment: Thanks that's worked a treat, I'll try with different batchsizes. Do you want to answer the question and 'll accept it as an answer, and thanks once again, this really had me stumped :)